# Can I use a value stored in a table as a key in another table?

Tags: csv, parsing, lua, lua-table, love2d

I'm new to LUA and I still haven't gotten the hang of how classes work in LUA, so my question
probably has a very simple answer. I'm trying to make a function that takes a CSV file and turns it into a lua table.

The input file would be something like this

```
PropertyKey1,Propertykey2,Propertykey3
object1property1,object1property2,object1property3
object2property1,object2property2,object2property3
object3property1,object3property2,object3property3
```

and I want the resulting lua table to look something like this

```
objects = {
    {
      PropertyKey1 = object1property1
      PropertyKey2 = object1property2
      PropertyKey3 = object1property3
    }
    {
      PropertyKey1 = object2property1
      PropertyKey2 = object2property2
      PropertyKey3 = object2property3
    }
    {
      PropertyKey1 = object3property1
      PropertyKey2 = object3property2
      PropertyKey3 = object3property3
    }
}
```

this is what I have thus far

```
function loadcsv(path)
  local OutTable = {}
  local file = io.open(path, "r")
  local linecount = 0

  for line in file:lines() do
    local data = {}
    local headers = {}
    local headerkey = 1

    if linecount < 1 then
      for val in line:gmatch("([^,]+),?") do
        table.insert(headers, val)
      end
    else
      for word in line:gmatch("([^,]+),?") do
        key = headers[headerkey]
        data[headerkey] = word
        headerkey = headerkey + 1
        table.insert(OutTable, data)
      end
    end

    linecount = linecount + 1
  end

  file:close()
  return OutTable
end
```

The above code does not run. When I try to print any of the values, they come as nil.
The problem is this bit

```
        key = headers[headerkey]
        data[headerkey] = word
```

I wanted to use the values I stored in one table as keys on the second table, but it looks like since LUA only passes the references, that doesn't work.

I did a quick experiment to confirm it. I first set up 2 tables.

```
  test = {}
  test2 = {}
  test[1]={"index"}
  key = test[1]
  key2 = "index"
```

First I tried assigning the value directly form the table

```
  test2[test[1]] = "text"
  print(test2.index)        --This did not work
```

then I tried going trough another variable

```
  test2[key] = "texto"
  print(test2.index)        --This did not work
```

I even tried using tostring()

```
  key = tostring(test[1])
  test2[key] = "texto"
  print(test2.index)        --This did not work
```

I wrote the string directly in the variable "key2" to confirm that I was using the right notation.

```
  test2[key2] = "text"
  print(test2.index)        --This one worked
```

I read a bit on metatables, but I'm not fully clear on those. Would that be the simplest way to do what I'm trying to do, or is my approach flawed in some other way?

Comment: Every single one of your "This did not work" examples [actually works just fine](https://www.ideone.com/YAZhBj). You have a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

```
key = headers[headerkey]
```

`key` is not used so why assign a value to it?

```
 data[headerkey] = word
```

`headerkey` is a numeric key. You start at 1 for each line and add 1 for each word in a line. So you end up with

```
data = {
  [1] = "object1property1",
  [2] = "object1property2",
  [3] = "object1property3"
}
```

Instead of the intended

```
data = {
  PropertyKey1 = "object1property1",
  PropertyKey2 = "object1property2",
  PropertyKey3 = "object1property3"
}
```

So you probably meant to write

```
local key = headers[headerkey]
data[key] = word
```

But you have to move headers out of the loop. Otherwise you'll end up with an empty table for line 1 resulting in `key` being `nil` which would cause Lua errors for using a nil table index.

The following line is called for every word

```
 table.insert(OutTable, data)
```

You need to do this for every line!

Your code basically produces this output:

```
local tableA = {"object1property1", "object1property2", "object1property3"}
local tableB = {"object2property1", "object2property2", "object2property3"}
local tableC = {"object3property1", "object3property2", "object3property3"}
OutTable = {
  tableA, tableA, tableA, tableB, tableB, tableB, tableC, tableC, tableC
}
```

I suggest you formulate your program in your first language and then translate it into Lua. This helps to avoid such errors.

Your problem is not related to metatables, classes or anything else mentioned. You simply used the wrong variable and messed up your inner loop.